# Apache Beam/Dataflow ReShuffle deprecated, what to use instead?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Apache Beam's [Reshuffle](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Reshuffle.java) was marked as deprecated [in May 2017](https://github.com/apache/beam/commit/e0b3f8064b97d8678e75bf6ba25244bca31e6a7d) with the note

> **For internal use only; no backwards compatibility guarantees.**

In addition, the DataflowRunner installs a [`ReshuffleOverrideFactory`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/1dafb5480fe329946dd34bc78c0f362620a4db4b/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/ReshuffleOverrideFactory.java) which I'm unclear of how changes the reshuffling.

Anyway, the JavaDoc doesn't mention what to use instead. How are users supposed do deal with ParDo transforms with high fan out in general and on Dataflow?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at `withFanout` option in `GroupByKey` and `Combine` operation. Here is the link to the Java API - https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.Globally.html#withFanout-int-